# Why am I getting "I/O operation on closed file" with PILLOW 3.1.0?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to convert a `tiff`  file into a `PDF` using `Pillow` and `PyPDF`. I was able to get this to work using an earlier version of `Pillow`, although I cannot which version.

I recently upgraded to `Pillow 3.1.0`, and now I ran into issues. This is the previously working code.

```
import os
import traceback

from PIL import Image
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger

to_merge = []

with Image.open('my_tif.tif') as img:
    seeker = 0

    while True:
        try: 
            # temp file name for PDF
            img_pdf = 'temp_{}.pdf'.format(seeker)

            #seeks to next image with TIFF
            img.seek(seeker)

            # saves the image as a PDF
            img.save(img_pdf)

            seeker += 1
            to_merge.append(img_pdf)

        except Exception as err:
            traceback.print_exc()
            break                

merger = PdfFileMerger()
for f in to_merge:
    merger.append(PdfFileReader(f))
    os.remove(f)
merger.write('merged.pdf')
```

Beforehand, it generated a PDF for each image within the `tiff` and then merged the PDFs together with no problem.

After I upgraded to `Pillow 3.1.0` it loops through all of the images, but then throws a `ValueError` on the final image.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Code/Python/tiff_to_pdf.py", line 16, in <module>
    img.save(img_pdf)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1675, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 155, in _save
    im.seek(pageNumber)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 930, in seek
    self._seek(max(frame, 0))  # Questionable backwards compatibility.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 956, in _seek
    self.fp.seek(self._frame_pos[frame])
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

What would be the cause of the `ValueError`?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

There can be two problems.

- `Image.Image.seek()` 
  If the image is a single-frame image, the file will be closed in this
  method after the frame is read. If the image is a multi-frame image, (e.g.
  multipage TIFF and animated GIF) the image file is left open so that
  `Image.Image.seek()` can load the appropriate frame.
- `Image.Image.close()` 
  Closes the file and destroys the core image object.
  The Pillow context manager will also close the file, but will not destroy
  the core image object.

**Solution**

1. If you are using `Image.Image.seek()` function to read the image and want to
   re-use the image again without opening it.

   What you can do, is copy the loaded image into another variable and perform
   operation.

   ```
   loaded_image = Image.open("test.jpg")
   temp = loaded_image.copy()
   ```

   Now you can use `temp.sheek()` to read the image and your loaded image
   will be safe
2. If you are not using `Image.Image.seek()` and facing the same issue then
   you are using `Image.Image.close()` function that is destroying the
   image.

   So, do not use `Image.Image.close()` if you want to re use the image.

**Solution Source**

[File Handling in Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/open_files.html) **Read the Image Lifecycle section**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. The only solution I found was to open the file as a file object and pass that to Image.Open on each iteration:

```
with open('my_tif.tif', 'rb') as f:
    seeker = 0

    while True:
        try: 
            img = Image.open(f)  
            # temp file name for PDF
            img_pdf = 'temp_{}.pdf'.format(seeker)

             #seeks to next image with TIFF
             img.seek(seeker)

             # saves the image as a PDF
             img.save(img_pdf)

             seeker += 1
             to_merge.append(img_pdf)

        except Exception as err:
            traceback.print_exc()
            break
```

Comment: I would also suggest catcing the **EOFError** exception to see if seek has no more pages.

Comment: Unfortunately I attempted this solution and still received the error. I have a feeling it is a bug with >=3.0. I downgraded to 2.9.0, and my issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

I also occur this issue in Pillow 5.4.1, downgraded to 5.0.0 was resolved.

```
File "/home1/irteam/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/home1/irteam/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home1/irteam/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "/home1/irteam/deploy/oneapp-clover/doc_base/clover/profilehandler.py", line 73, in get
    image, tmp_error_code = yield loadUserImage(user_no, hash_id, headers)
  File "/home1/irteam/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home1/irteam/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/home1/irteam/deploy/oneapp-clover/doc_base/clover/merge_profile.py", line 273, in loadUserImage
    setCache(user_cache_key, image_file.getvalue())
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```