# Python - Pillow - Can't save resized image - Error seek of closed file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I've been at this for a couple of hours. I'm trying to resize an image via pillow and save it but I continue to get the error `Error seek of closed file` and I'm not sure why. I've looked at numerous tutorials and it seems to work fine for them. When I run in the ipython shell, with `.show()` it seems to run fine.

from my research/understanding, it's throwing an error because it believes the file is still open when trying to do actions to it, but these actions should be fine since I'm interactive with the image. Any help is appreciated

I've also tried running with `with Image.open(file) as img:` and indenting the code below and removing the `img.close()` line but I still get the same error.

Here is my code:

```
def resize_image(file):
    
    img = Image.open(file) #opens image

    #new dims to resize to 
    orig_height = int(img.height)
    orig_width = int(img.width)
    orig_height_to_140_ratio = orig_height / 140
    new_height = 140
    new_width = int(orig_width / orig_height_to_140_ratio)


    resized_img = img.resize( #resize
        (new_width, new_height), resample=Image.BICUBIC)


    new_image = resized_img.save(new_name) #save

    img.close() #close open image

    return new_image #returns the image
```

Comment: Why are you making a copy of your image in the first place? Why not just `img.save(filename)` followed by a `return img`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Pillows documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/open_files.html#file-handling) you should close the file from which you load the image before saving to it. Try moving `img.close()` just above the `resized_img.save` and then run it.
You could also look into [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069835/why-am-i-getting-i-o-operation-on-closed-file-with-pillow-3-1-0)